Ignore Self-Certificate with RestTemplate in a Simple and Standard Way
Is there a simple way to allow uncertifiable REST responses with RestTemplate without throwing an error?
The solution is and won't be able to use any ISPs, Certificate Authorities (CAs), or many package additions. This is a closed-circuit environment.
Please note this expects long-term maintenance and upgradability with the rest of package dependency updates, and won't (realistically) be able to revert-or-refactor as decision should be assumed outside of sphere-of-control.
So, I'm looking for built-in and/or least-impact changes to accommodate further decisions, direction changes, and project growth.
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "web.site": 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target; 
nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have been able to get by with other examples like below. Utilizing some @Autowired and @PostConstruct does help minimize the amount of overall custom code being made and continuously reused. But, I'd think that in 2024 there have been more updates to the Spring Framework and are more direct RestTemplate flags, its Spring Boot configurations, and Spring Framework arguments, that have been made. This seems like standard situation to accommodate for: responsible security, enterprise scaling, and/or professional centonization.
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (cert, authType) -> true;
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
        .register("https", sslsf).register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory()).build();
BasicHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(
        socketFactoryRegistry);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

I do understand this and other suggested answers in older forums meet the minimum criteria of accepting a network locked and/or (at least) restricted environment. This is a request to ask-and-prompt a direct question for a standard(ized) way of ignoring-and/or-accepting authentication from: self-signed, unverified, and/or insecure security certificates (SSL, TLS, HTTPS). This is different from asking for any answer, including but not limited to: hacks, custom code, and/or anti-patterns.
